# Json get a parameter can't access on it iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

That's an example

```
{
"updated":1350213484,
"id":"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q\u003dProva\u0026output\u003djson",
"title":"Risultati di feed per \"Prova\"",
"self":[
{
"href":"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q\u003dProva\u0026output\u003djson"
}
],
"items":[
{
"title":"Home Page - La prova del cuoco",
"id":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/",
"updated":1350213485,
"feed":[
{
"href":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/dl/portali/site/page/Page-ffb545b4-9e72-41e5-866f-a465588c43fa-rss.html"
}
],
"alternate":[
{
"href":"http://www.laprovadelcuoco.rai.it/",
"type":"text/html"
}
],
"content":{
"direction":"ltr",
"content":"Diventa un cuoco provetto con “La Prova del Cuoco”: le videoricette in un' applicazione di facile e veloce consultazione per il tuo Iphone. Scopri come acquistare ..."
}
},
{
"title":"Le prove Invalsi di matematica e italiano",
"id":"http://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/quartaprova/",
"updated":1350213486,
"feed":[
{
"href":"http://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/quartaprova/feed/"
}
],
"alternate":[
{
"href":"http://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/quartaprova/",
"type":"text/html"
}
],
"content":{
"direction":"ltr",
"content":"Un sito Zanichelli dedicato alle prove Invalsi di italiano e matematica: esercitazioni, consigli, informazioni utili, novità, aggiornamenti e blog d'autore sulle prove ..."
}
},
```

How can I get the feed URL?

That's what I do

```
NSString *daParsare=[reader searchFeed:searchText];



NSArray *items = [[daParsare JSONValue] objectForKey:@"items"];

for (NSDictionary *item in items) {



    NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *feed = [item valueForKeyPath:@"feed.href"];


}
[tab reloadData];
```

With the title everything is ok but when I try to access to the feed paramater I get the error...

Comment: You can't use the key path because the object that contains the href attribute is in an array in your JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *feed = [item valueForKeyPath:@"feed.href"];
```

is wrong, as `feed` refers to an array, that again holds a dictionary.

```
NSString *feed = [[[item objectForKey:@"feed"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"href"];
```

If you are using an modern Xcode, this last line is the same as in Jason Cocos answer.

```
NSString* feed = item[@"feed"][0][@"href"];
```

this syntax is called [Object Subscription](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: Niceeeeee! That code works! You rock... but for the content parameter? I tried the same using  NSString *feed = [[[item objectForKey:@"content"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"content"]; but it fail!

Comment: content is not an array, but an dictionary. `[[item objectForKey:@"content"] objectForKey:@"content"];` or `valueForKeyPath:@"content.content"`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON object is named `jsonObject`, you would simply access the `href` element. So, in your current object, the URL is in an object named `href`, which is the first (and in this case, only) element in an array named `feed` at the top level:

```
NSString* urlString = jsonObject[@"feed"][0][@"href"];
```

You should check to make sure that if `feed` exists, it's not an empty array before you access one of its elements.

Comment: This syntax is valid only for ios5?

Comment: I've added info to my question

Comment: The syntax is valid for iOS 4.3 and above, the same as ARC.

Comment: @UsiUsi you need to compile it with Xcode 4.5, but you can target as far back as 4.0. It's just a compiler addition that make the code easier to read, but is effectively the same as `-objectForKey:` and `-objectAtIndex:`